# Using mod_rewrite to mask a directory/file name in a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've taken my site down for some prolonged maintenance and am using mod_rewrite to send all requests to a single page: `www.mysite.com/temp/503.php`

This is my .htaccess file which works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/temp/503.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* /temp/503.php [R,L]
```

However, what I'd also like to be able to do is to hide `/temp/503.php` in the resulting URL from the visitor.

I know this is perhaps trivial and I'm sure fairly simple to achieve, but with my limited mod_rewrite skills I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the `R` flag in the rewrite rule, which tells the rule to **redirect the request**, thus changing the URL in the browser's location bar. So the rule would look like:

```
RewriteRule .* /temp/503.php [L]
```

which internally rewrites the requested URI instead of externally telling the browser that it's been moved to a new URL.

Comment: Thanks for that Jon. Works as advertised.